# Doubly Linked List search without traversal

Tags: doubly-linked-list

How to search an element in a doubly linked list without traversing the linked list and deleting any node from it?

I'm looking for solutions but I'm getting stuck with the conditions provided. It's simple with the deletion process, you simply check the beginning node and keep on deleting if not present. But that is also not allowed.

Comment: Traversing is not the same as deleting. You simply need to keep a pointer to the *current* node, and advance the pointer to the next after you've checked it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to search for an element in any type of linked list without traversing. Note search in linked list take O(n)

Comment: hey mark, even i thought the same thing! that is the only possibility i could think of